# How to set Modal Value with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my script to call the data

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tmpsurat').click(function() {
      var id=$(this).data('id');
      var url ='{{URL('/cekSuratKelengkapan')}}/'+id;
      $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : url,
        dataType  : 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
          $('#surat').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            console.log(data);
              modal.find("#id").val(data[0].a);
            });
        }
      });
    });
});</script>
```

```
<a class='tmpsurat' data-id='$val->idKelengkapan' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#surat'> <i class='fa fa-check' style=color:#28a745;></i></a>
```

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="surat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content ">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ceklist Surat</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="ill do it later" method="post" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nama">Nama Reseller</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputnama" placeholder="Masukan Nama Reseller" id="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nama">Modal</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id2" id="id2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id3" id="id3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id4" id="id4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id5" id="id5">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the button the modal shows up but the value of #id would not show the value of the data that I get from the URL. I checked with the console log and the data are there, below are the result from the console log.

What I want is to assign each id - id 5 with idJenisSurat which I get from the URL.

```
[![screenshot console][1]][1]
```

Comment: `modal.find("#id").val(data[0].a);` is the culprit. If you pass no arguments into jQuery's `.val()` function, you will get the value of the input. If you pass a data into the function(`.val("Some new value such as your URL")`), then the content will be changed.

Comment: mind to explain it a lil bit more ? im new to this ajax stuff ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your json and then use  `.val(v.idJenisSurat)`
to assign value inside inputs .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tmpsurat').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    /**var url = '{{URL(' / cekSuratKelengkapan ')}}/' + id;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {*/
      //suppose this is return from ajax
    var data = [{
        "a": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "idJenisSurat": 1
      },
      {
        "a": 5,
        "status": 1,
        "idJenisSurat": 5
      }, {
        "a": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "idJenisSurat": 2
      }, {
        "a": 3,
        "status": 1,
        "idJenisSurat": 3
      }, {
        "a": 4,
        "status": 1,
        "idJenisSurat": 4
      }
    ]
      //loop through jsons..
      $(data).each(function(i, v) {
        i++;
        $(`#id${i}`).val(v.idJenisSurat);//assign value
      })
   
    /* }
    });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class='tmpsurat' data-id='$val->idKelengkapan' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#surat'> <i class='fa fa-check' style=color:#28a745;>Click</i></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="surat" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ceklist Surat</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="ill do it later" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nama">Nama Reseller</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputnama" placeholder="Masukan Nama Reseller" id="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nama">Modal</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id1" id="id1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id2" id="id2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id3" id="id3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id4" id="id4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id5" id="id5">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. i guess the reason it wont work because i need to loop it first right ? .. thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
modal.find("#id").val(data[0].a);
```

To this:

```
$("#id").val(data[0].a);
```